# Comparing current time with end time given by user in PHP

Tags: php

I am comparing current time with given time.but i am getting wrong results.

```
  <?php 
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
    //echo date("h:i a");
    //echo $query2['endtime'];
    if(date("h:i a") > $query2['endtime'])
    {
    $date = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d"));
    $date->modify('+1 day');
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
    echo '<input type="date" name="date" id="date" min="'.$date->format('Y-m-d').'">';
    }
    else
    {
    echo '<input type="date" name="date" id="date" min="'.date("Y-m-d").'">';
    }

    ?>
```

I have endtime using $query2['endtime'] from the database and I have cheched using echo.My end time is 5:00 pm.But I am getting wrong results .Please Help.

Comment: You need to use strtotime() to make timestamp and check

Comment: Can you explain @AzeezKallayi.

Comment: I have added a sample code as answer. please have a look

Comment: in which format your time is stored in db.

Comment: 5:00 pm In that user is entering .So I am fetching that.@Nasir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since date() function will give you date string , you cannot check '>' operation on that. First you need to convert date string into timestamp using strtotime() then compare. Below code may help you

```
<?php 
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
echo date("h:i a");
$query2= '05:00 pm';
$query21 =strtotime($query2);
echo $query21;
if(strtotime(date("h:i a")) > $query21)
{
    echo "yes";
}
else
{
    echo "no";
}
?>
```

Comment: if(strtotime(date("h:i a")) > strtotime($query2['endtime'])).It will work or not.

Comment: Yes. if your $query2['endtime'] is in this format : '05:00 pm'

Comment: Yes it is form 5:00 pm.

Comment: I strongly recommend continuing with the DateTime class, as the OP had started on, instead of the old date-manipulation library. It'll make things a whole lot easier in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

You should use timestamps everywhere but when displaying to user due to its consistency in form, and ability to move around anywhere.

I suggest you should dave times as `"INSERT INTO xx VALUES(etc, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), etc, etc)"`

And then use `time()` in php to compare the result. You can also convert it to a presentable format by using date().

UPDATE:

assuming you now have `$query2['endtime']` as a timestamp, just do

```
if(time()>$query2['endtime']){
    //true
}


 //and to show to user
 echo date('Y-m-d', $query2['endtime']);
```

Comment: if(strtotime(date("h:i a")) > strtotime($query2['endtime'])).It will work or not.

Comment: That is because i am suggesting you use timestamps when storing and comparing dates. re read my answer

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you're already using the DateTime class, you'll find that it's quite trivial to compare them. Like this:

```
<?php 

// Create the dtz object once, and save it for re-use
$dtz = new DateTimeZone ("Asia/Kolkata");

// With the first parameter set to null it'll use the current time as well.
// So I'm using "midnight" here to emulate the results of your old code.
$date = new DateTime ("midnight", $dtz);

// Now we can create a DateTime object for the user-supplied date.
$endDate = new DateTime ($query2['endtime'], $dtz);

// Since both are DateTime objects we can now compare them directly.
if ($date > $endDate)
{
    $date->modify ('+1 day');
    echo $date->format ('Y-m-d');
}

echo '<input type="date" name="date" id="date" min="'.$date->format("Y-m-d").'">';
```

Comment: Thank you very much.@ChristianF

Comment: You're welcome. Made a slight change to the code just now, btw. To avoid duplicating code unnecessarily. The two echo-lines were basically identical, as the date would be "today" anyway if the condition isn't true.
Please remember to upvote and (if possible) accept the best answer to your question. :)

Comment: Okay Thank you Very Much.